# How worn is this chainring?

Tags: chainring, sprocket

I have the chainring shown below. It's the front sprocket of an ebike. Does this chainring need replacing or are the teeth still OK?

[image]

Comment: One test you can do is to attempt to pull the chain away from the sprocket near the front.  If you can pull the chain far enough that it's almost to the top of the closest tooth then either the chain or sprocket (or both) is at end of life.

Comment: Perfectly OK but rather dirty.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Shows some wear, but looks OK.

All teeth look symmetrical and so do the spaces between them. Really worn teeth look like a swept back shark dorsal fin or develop a visible burr.

Do a Google image search for 'worn chainring teeth' and you'll get plenty of examples.

Comment: That said, a chainring is cheap and if you have it apart now you might as well replace it now.

Comment: Definitely needs cleaning

Comment: @RoboKaren Are ebike chainrings as cheap as regular ones?

Comment: Like it’s around $20: http://www.motostrano.com/SRAM-PC-EX1-8-speed-Chain-Motostrano-com-p/710845793622.htm?dfw_tracker=12507-710845793622&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI4P-v7p2E3gIVhNlkCh24qwudEAQYASABEgJp0PD_BwE

Comment: I'd clean and refit it, should last for at least one more full chain.  Depends on your cost of labour, the value of your time.

Comment: This chainring costs about $50 as it is a 22t Miranda chainring with 3mm offset — relatively rare.

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk All the more reason to just reuse it. A worn single-speed sprocket looks *very* different, and it won't fail you before it looses at least two *consecutive* teeth. This is also very different from worn chain-shift sprockets: The single-speed sprockets have long teeth that actually go through the entire depth of the chain, while chain-shift sprockets use very short teeth to ease shifting. Deformed teeth do increase chain wear, but chains are much cheaper than $50, so I would likely wait with replacing such an expensive sprocket until it starts loosing teeth.

Comment: Btw: The google search for 'worn chainring teeth' provides you mostly with many images of chainrings *for chain-shift bikes*. These can take a *lot* less wear without failing than the sprocket shown in the question. Thus, I believe that this google search is not really helpful in assessing the state of the sprocket in question.

Answer (score 1):

Although the texture appears to be rusted/worn, the actual chainring itself seems to be okay. As someone said, the teeth are symmetrical as are the spaces in between each one. If this is the case, then you should be all good.

Comment: Hello, this is a very informative answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't offer any additional information beyond what has already been posted and accepted as an answer. Stack Exchange is designed to accumulate quality, distinct answers, so posting a duplicate answer is contrary to the mission of SE.